# Error Incorrect syntax

Tags: t-sql, sybase

I have created a procedure in Sybase

```sql
create procedure prcrms_crms_cust_id_verify_ins(@customer_code numeric(12,0),@id_type tinyint,@verification_status varchar(12),@verification_response varchar(255),@verification_date datetime,@add_user varchar(21)) as 
begin
 declare @check_id_exists int
  select @check_id_exists = count(*) from crms_customer_id_verification where ( ('customer_code'=@customer_code) and ('id_type'=@id_type))
  if(@check_id_exists > 0)
  begin
    update crms_customer_id_verification set verification_status=@verification_status,verification_response=@verification_response,verification_date=@verification_date where  ( ('customer_code'=@customer_code) and ('id_type'=@id_type))
    return @@rowcount
  end
  if((@check_id_exists <> null) or  (@check_id_exists <> 0))
  begin
    insert into crms_customer_id_verification(customer_code,id_type,verification_status,verification_response,verification_date,add_user) values(@customer_code,@id_type,@verification_status,@verification_response,@verification_date,@add_user)
      return  @@rowcount 
  end
end
```

when i try to execute the procedure

```sql
exec prcrms_crms_cust_id_verify_ins(3344,0,"VERIFIED",'{test:test}','1998-09-09 12:12:12.000','Admin')
```

> it shows Incorrect syntax near '3344'.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
/*
create  procedure prcrms_crms_cust_verify_ins(@customer_code varchar(255),@id_type varchar(255) ,@verification_status varchar(12),@verification_response varchar(255),@verification_date varchar(255),@add_user varchar(21))as 
/*
** ------------------------------------
** Created By   : Bibil Mathew Chacko
** Created On   : Jul 16 2016
** Description : insert in crms_customer_id_verification if id_type and customer exist.Update table if customer and id_type  exist.
** -------------------------------------
*/
begin
 declare

     @check_id_exists   int,
     @cc                numeric,
     @id_t              tinyint,
     @vd                datetime            


     select  @cc    =   convert(numeric(12,0),@customer_code)
     select  @id_t  =   convert(tinyint,@id_type)
     select  @vd    =   convert(datetime,@verification_date)

  select @check_id_exists = count(*) from crms_customer_id_verification where ( (customer_code=@cc) and (id_type=@id_t))
  if(@check_id_exists > 0)
  begin
    update crms_customer_id_verification set verification_status=@verification_status,verification_response=@verification_response,verification_date=@vd where  (customer_code=@cc and id_type=@id_t)
    return @@rowcount
  end
  if((@check_id_exists <> null) or  (@check_id_exists <> 0))
  begin
    insert into crms_customer_id_verification(customer_code,id_type,verification_status,verification_response,verification_date,add_user) values(@cc,@id_t,@verification_status,@verification_response,@vd,@add_user)
      return  @@rowcount 
  end
end

*/
/*exec prcrms_crms_cust_verify_ins '3344','0',"VERIFIED",'{test:test}','1998-09-09 12:12:12.000','Admin'*/
```

Should use VARCHAR type as parameter and procedure should have support for  converting to required type. Another mistake I have done is Sybase Procedures don't have parenthesis.

Comment: The only problem was the parenthesis. I'm not sure why you would need to use `varchar` (that at least is not clear from both the question and this answer).